# Empty object after killing app: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method '' on a null object reference

Tags: javascript, java, android

I am creating an app. I add a html, css and js file into the webview. I also build up several databases (sqldatabase) to store data. Js is used to add, delete and update data in databases. The reason why I build database is that app will be killed in the background after the user had click "home" button for while. Databases can help rebuild the whole html and continue running the app.

I found some problems in the coding of js. After amendment, an error still remains:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.sahelper.ContentTableDataBase.deleteData(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

I check and find out that the database become null after killing the app.
However, the problem above does not exist if the app is not killed. It occures if and only if the app is killed. My problem is: why the database is null after the app is killed. How shall I declare my database?

Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    HTMLDataBase myDB1;
    ContentTableDataBase myDB2;
    CloudTableDataBase myDB3;
    InterviewDataBase myDB4;
    Context context;
    boolean check;

    private WebView view;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myDB1 = new HTMLDataBase(this);
        myDB2 = new ContentTableDataBase(this);
        myDB3 = new CloudTableDataBase(this); 
        myDB4 = new InterviewDataBase(this); 

        display_html();
        Javascript_Android_Communication();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        myDB1 = new HTMLDataBase(this); 
        myDB2 = new ContentTableDataBase(this); 
        myDB3 = new CloudTableDataBase(this);
        myDB4 = new InterviewDataBase(this);

        display_html();
        Javascript_Android_Communication();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();

        this.finish();
    }

    public void display_html()
    {
        WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }

    public void Javascript_Android_Communication()
    {
        WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {});
        WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        view.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
        view.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewJavaScriptInterface(this), "app");
    }
}
```

Comment: so, you try to interact with an app that's already killed? How should that not lead to problems?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Do you mean that I cannot rebuild the connection between js in webview and database after killing the app, even I can rebuild the whole html in the webview by the data extracted from database. If yes, then why can I still extract data from database by using js inside the html?

Comment: your database might still be up and running, but your instance of ContentTableDataBase, which is created and exists within your app, is not

Comment: Is there any way to recreate a connection between database and js inside the webveiw?

Comment: you could .... not kill your app?

Comment: I do not want to kill my app. The problem is, android will kill my app and there is no way to prevent it from happening (at least no gereral solution in my understanding). And a big trouble will occur if my app is killed (Basically the app will become useless). If there is no way to prevent killing app from happening, the only way I can think of is building a database to store data that I have entered and rebuild the whole webview after app is killed.

Comment: if your app is killed, your app can no longer be used, that is a fact. But why is your code divided over several apps?

Comment: If app cannot be used after killed, then all app shall be reinitialized (e.g. within a few hours). But why some apps can still keep unchanged and of course can be used no matter how long it takes, e.g. alarm clock app?

Comment: simple, because they're not being killed. You should look into why your app is being killed

Comment: Can I protect my app from killed by builing a Foreground Service in my app?

Comment: has it ever dawned to you this might rather be an issue with your android configuration, than it is with your code? Yes, that might do the trick, but is that what you want/need for your app? https://www.howtogeek.com/762936/how-to-stop-android-from-killing-background-apps/#:~:text=Scroll%20down%20and%20select%20%22Battery,That's%20pretty%20much%20it!